# Programatically create and mount components with vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to programatically create and mount components on the fly from parent component.

It works fine with Vue 2.

```js
import Vue from 'vue' 

// ParentComponent.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    createChild() {
      const Child = Vue.extend(ChildComponent)
      const child = new Child({
        propsData,
        store: this.$store,
        i18n: this.$i18n
      }).$mount()
    }
  }
}
```

But I cannot figure out how-to do with Vue 3.

Comment: What about using in-template component rendering instead, like `<component v-bind:is="childComponent">` instead?

Comment: I don't think this is a rendering issue, but more about having the flexibility to programatically instantiate components on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally ended with this, after finding some info here:

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/1802
- https://github.com/pearofducks/mount-vue-component

```js
// ParentComponent.vue
import { h, render } from 'vue' 

export default {
  methods: {
    createChild() {
      const child = h(ChildComponent, propsData)
      child.appContext = this.$.appContext  // use store, i18n
      const el = document.createElement('div')
      render(node, el)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your `node` variable? where is it set?